# Виджет Accordion не корректно отображается в виджете Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Есть View:

**Schools.cshtml**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Район:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AreaNames, Model.AreaNames, "--Выбрать--", new { @id = "ddlArea"})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Образовательная организация:</label>
        </td>
        <td id="School">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SchoolNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Выбрать--", new { @id = "ddlSchool", @class="ttt" });
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Отчеты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Реквизиты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1"></div>                    
    <div id="tabs-2"></div>         
</div>                  

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
    $('#School').change(function () {
        var schoolid = $("#ddlSchool").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Report/GetRMschoolPV?_schoolID=" + schoolid,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tabs-1").html(data);
            }
        })
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetSchoolinfoPV?_schoolID=" + schoolid,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#tabs-2").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
...   
</script>
```

При изменении значения в раскрывающем списке `School` вызываются две функции AJAX, которые от сервера получают два частичных представления и помещает их в соответствующие вкладки. Частичное представление, помещающая во вкладку `tabs-1` имеет виджет `Accordion`:

**_RMschool.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Monit95App.Services.Work.Concrete.RMschool>                   

<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
</head>
<body>
    <br />
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>2016/2017 учебный год</h3>
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Проект</th>
                        <th>Отчет</th>
                        <th>Учебный год</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var reportMeta in Model.Where(x => x.year == "2016/2017").OrderByDescending(x => x.code))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@reportMeta.ProjectName</td>
                        <td><a href="@reportMeta.WWWref" style="color:royalblue">@reportMeta.name</a></td>
                        <td>@reportMeta.year</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>

        <h3>2015/2016 учебный год</h3>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-inverse">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Проект</th>
                        <th>Отчет</th>
                        <th>Учебный год</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach (var reportMeta in Model.Where(x => x.year == "2015/2016").OrderByDescending(x => x.code))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@reportMeta.ProjectName</td>
                        <td><a href="@reportMeta.WWWref" style="color:royalblue">@reportMeta.name</a></td>
                        <td>@reportMeta.year</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true            
        });
    });
</script>
```

И все работает и отображается правильно, **если на момент выбора из списке** `School`, **активной является вкладка** `tabs-1` (отчеты):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** Но вот если при выборе школы вместо вкладки `Отчеты` будет активна вкладка `Реквизиты`, и затем передя уже на вкладку `Отчеты` можно встретить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Частичное представление загрузилось в "Отчеты", но вот сам виджет `Accordion` не раскрывается полностью. Почему так происходит?

**Вариант** который предлагают [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542161/jquery-ui-accordions-within-tabs) - сначала активировать accordion, а затем tabs

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

не совсем подходит, т.к. у меня accordion находиться в частичном представлении и попадает в tabs уже отрендированным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось: виджет `accordion` **работает правильно если в момент загрузки его во вкладку именно это вкладка -** `Отчеты` **является активной**.

*Решение*

```
$('#School').change(function () {        
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        active: 0
    });
    $("[tabindex='-1']").removeClass('ui-state-active');
    $("[tabindex='-1']").removeClass('ui-tabs-active');
```

*Пояснение*

Т.е. перед тем как залить какие-то данные в `tabs`:

1. Cначала актируется первая вкладка, где у нас наш accordion;
2. А затем подсветка для вкладки *Реквизиты* убирается. Если это не
   сделать, то на экране будет содержимое первой вкладки, а выделенные
   синим будут обе.